# Menus not showing in Gnome Terminal on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal

My gnome terminal has stopped showing the menu bars when I mouse over the top bar. I'm not sure why this is happening. I did a full update (`apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade`) and then rebooted, but that didn't do anything. I even tried changing my shell to see if something in my profile was causing this behavior, but that didn't work either. Is this a bug, or do I have something set wrong?

<strike>Another error that showed up around the same time is that when in `tmux` pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> causes `^P` to be written to the terminal. Could these two errors be related?</strike> After resetting my gnome-terminal settings this problem still exists, so it is unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

I found that deleting (or moving in my case) the gnome terminal config located at `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/%gconf.xml` and rebooting causes the menu to reappear. I've posted my config [here](https://gist.github.com/emandres/c1593dfee54e59050a40) for anyone who's interested (the commented line 6 was the cause of the problem).

I'm unsure how I got the setting on line 6 set. Looking at the settings dialog for gnome terminal, there's nothing that I see that seems like it would cause that behavior.

**Edit**

Found the setting. I'm not sure how I missed before, or why I clicked it in the first place. I don't know how this "feature" could ever be a good thing to have, since you can't get back into the settings to set it back.

[image]

Comment: By the way, right-clicking on the terminal window shows a popup menu. One of the menu items is a "Show Menubar" toggle. So you can get the menubar back and get to the preferences dialog.

Comment: I had the same issue after running a setup script that created a %gconf.xml file on a clean install of 15.10.  The highlighted setting does not show up in the preferences in 15.10.  I deleted the %gconf.xml file and on reboot menu was operating as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn on the menu bar with this command in terminal:

```
gnome-terminal --show-menubar
```

It helped me to solve this problem, so I'm posting it here. I hope it will be useful for others.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu 16), going to System Settings > Appearance > Behaviour. Under the "Show the menus for a window", selecting "In the windows title bar", solved it.